# Integrate via Shell Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Use shell integration to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the x-axis $x = 1 + (y-2)^2, x=2$

$x = 5 + y^2 - 4y \\ y^2 - 4y + 3 = 0 \\ y = 1, 3$

$$2\pi \int_{1}^{3} y(5+y^2-4y)dy = 2\pi \int_{1}^{3} (5y+y^3-4y^2)dy \\
= 2\pi \bigg[  \frac{5y^2}{2} + \frac{y^4}{4} - \frac{4y^3}{3}\bigg]_{1}^{3} \\
= 2\pi \bigg( (\frac{45}{2} + \frac{81}{4} - \frac{108}{3}) - ( \frac{5}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{4}{3} ) \bigg) \\
= 2\pi (\frac{27}{4} - \frac{17}{12})\\
= 2\pi (\frac{16}{3}) = \frac{32\pi}{3}$$

However my textbook says the answer is $\frac{16\pi}{3}$. WolframAlpha answer also comes up as $\frac{32\pi}{3}$...is this just a textbook error? I'd appreciate a third opinion

Comment: What you have graphed there is $y=(x-2)^2+1$

Comment: The parabolas you have drawn are opening up and down, so are like $y=x^2$ format. But the parabola you are given is of $x=y^2$ format and should open to the right.

Comment: Hello, please see my above edit. I was able to work through the problem I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrand is slightly off.  The heights of your cylindrical shells are $2-(5+y^2-4y)$.  This makes the integral
$$2\pi \int_{1}^{3} y(2-(5+y^2-4y)) dy = \frac{16\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: so when I set the equation to zero and subtract x to the other side, really it becomes two functions instead of one? I suppose $x=2$ makes a straight line that serves as an upper range function for $[1,3]$ as well as allowing the calculation of the upper/lower bounds.

Comment: Think of it like how you would find area between two curves: top minus bottom.